# Create system image of android device to be used as one of the images in AVD

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I have test android devices. These devices are not normal android phones or tablets as they have special library to use the built-in hardwares such as printer. They are also bulkier than normal phones and tablets. As a result, it is always a hassle to bring them with me as I move around alot.

My goal is if I can upload the system images of my devices and test them using emulator, I can travel light!

Anyone please?

Comment: I am not aware of any means by which you can extract a system image from a device that will work in an emulator. Ask the device manufacturer if they have an emulator image that has an emulated version of their special library.

Comment: I will try that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can using a cloud backup system like [Google Drive](https://www.google.com/drive/) or [Microsoft One Drive](https://onedrive.live.com/), but i think they have a 5Gb upload limit per file even if you are using they payed version

You can also setup your own cloud backup system using your own server with a Linux OS like [FreeNAS](http://www.freenas.org/), or if you have a hardware NAS solution try to open your firewall to allow and forward the request to your NAS

The problem is that everytime you need a new image you have to download it from internet and the time depends on your connection